# How to remove some metaboxes for CPTs?

Tags: metabox

I remove some metaboxes using

```
remove_meta_box('commentsdiv','page','normal'); // Comments.
remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv','post','normal' ); // Comments.
```

It doesn't seem to apply to CPTs.
So to remove a metabox from all CPTs, is there an alternative to repeating the above but with the cpt name replacing page/post?

Answer (score 2):

@Jeffrey's answer is correct is you are the one registering the post types, simply remove the support argument for `comments`.

But if you want to remove it from *all* custom post types (that may be registered by plugins too) you can do:

```
$cptslugs = get_post_types( array('public'=>false, '_builtin' => false) , 'names', 'and');
foreach ($cptslugs as $cpt) {
    remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv', $cpt, 'normal' );
}
```

Comment: Great addition :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard meta boxes that are shown on Custom Post Types are determined by the support you've given to the post type in the [register_post_type()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function.

The function has a [supports](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#supports) argument that takes an array as value. In this array simply remove 'comments' and it won't show the comments meta boxes.

Comment: @ Jeffrey... thankyou - I'd forgotten that. My CPTs only support title/editor/excerpt/revisions/page-attributes, so I'm confused by one which has comments. I suspect this must be because I originally added some CPTs using a plugin, before I learned to manually add them. I've now deleted and re-added that entry and it's behaving as expected.

Comment: @majick... thanks. That's a useful snippet which I'll file and use if needed.